# "Boneular" vs. "bonular"

Tags: orthography, suffixes, vowels

My knowledge in morphology and orthography is lacking. I would like to know how to spell the neologism *boneular*, from *bone* (or *Backbone*, a programming library used for creating Web applications) and *modular*.

Would it be *bonular*? Or a less likely *boneular*?

Comment: So this is a made up word?

Comment: A backbone modular unit is a *[vertebra](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertebra#Noun)*

Comment: @Mitch yes, i'm attempting to create a project name similar to named similar to Backbone, a programming library.

Comment: @jwpat7 , thanks! vertebrae might actually work better!
I've added some more context as to what Backbone refers too.

Comment: It has to be *boneular*, with the ***e***, to reflect the roots -- on the other hand, *bonular* would suggest *bon* (=good)+ *(mod)-ular*. I do not think *bone* can represent your *backbone*, though, which is a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bonular* appears to be the correct spelling for that pronunciation.  For example, in answerbag.com post [#572879](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/572879) (28 Jan 2008) Jodie44 wrote:

> Bonular, pronounced BONE-u-lar. I’ve used it a bunch of times because it seems right. As in, “I went to the doctor thinking I had a muscular problem, but it ended up being bonular.”

With fewer than 800 google hits, *bonular* is rare enough that you probably can adopt it as a project name without high risk of conflict.  However, I think the *modular* portion of your derivation does not survive being connected to *bone* (which might not matter, since you probably will have an explanatory paragraph for the name).

Comment: Yea I saw that as well, I was just worried I would have made an error where everyone was like... that's totally 'bon-you-lar', not 'bone-you-lar'.